# price alignment interest on future contract

Tags: futures, swaps, margin

why this is no PAI (price alignment interest) on a future contact like cleared swaps have?
Am I right that you may get interest from your margin account, but you do not need to pay the interest back to your counter party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog post might help:

[https://theotcspace.com/content/price-alignment-interest-pai#:~:text=PAI%20is%20the%20overnight%20cost,a%20CCP%20such%20as%20SwapClear](https://theotcspace.com/content/price-alignment-interest-pai#:%7E:text=PAI%20is%20the%20overnight%20cost,a%20CCP%20such%20as%20SwapClear).

Futures are settled daily, and thus considered "maturued" on each trading day. Hence, no PAI needs to be paid.